# PHP get class from stored string of full class path

Tags: php

I store a PHP Class name with the namespace as a string, in my database. Example:  `"App\Fields\TextField"`. Later on, based on that string, I want to read a static variable on the class, that the string defines. How could I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could actually just reach your variable like this:

```
namespace Foo;

class Test {

    public static $foo = "BAR";

}

$string = "Foo\Test";

var_dump($string::$foo); // Output: BAR
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option with [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.reflectionclass.php)

```
>>> namespace Test;
>>> class MainTest { public static $var = 'Work!';  }
>>> $class = 'Test\MainTest';
=> "Test\MainTest"
>>> (new \ReflectionClass($class))->getStaticPropertyValue('var');
=> "Work!"
```

If you wanna get all static vars:

```
>>> (new \ReflectionClass($class))->getStaticProperties();
=> [
     "var" => "Work!",
   ]
```